# Error 438 when copying data from closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel

every week I have to run a report, export it, manipulate it, add in the same forumulas, etc. So I figured I could probably just make a macro to do most of it for me.

I ended up creating a excel file with the forumulas so that I can just copy and paste it using VBA, however, I am getting error 438 object doesn't suppor this property or method on the line starting with wba.sheets

Here is the code.

```
    Dim wba As Workbook
Set wba = ThisWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Custom Office Templates\xxx.xlsx")
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F18").Copy
wba.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(2, -5).Paste
wb.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Try replacing `End(xlDown)`, with `End(xlUp)`.

Comment: Done so, knew it was cleaner but didnt know of the offset would change. Thinking back on it, sleep deprived thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim wba As Workbook
Set wba = ThisWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Custom Office Templates\xxx.xlsx")    
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F18").Copy
wba.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(2, -5).Select
Activesheet.Paste
wb.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xlDown will fail if there's nothing below F1, so it's typically safer to use xlUp (as @MarcoGetrost noted)

```
Dim wba As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Set wba = ThisWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Custom Office Templates\xxx.xlsx")

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F18").Copy _
         wba.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,"F").End(xlUp).Offset(2, -5)

wb.Close False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```